# Syntax highlighting in gedit not working automatically

Tags: ruby, gedit

I'm trying to use Ubuntu for Rails development and I'm liking gedit except the syntax highlighting does not seem to work with out me setting it for each file I open. Should it not recognize a `.rb` file a ruby file rather than me having to go into the menu and setting it as such?

Have I missed a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to edit your /etc/mime.types file and add those “text/x-????” entries:

```
  text/x-ruby-source                              rhtml html.erb erb
  text/x-eruby                                    rjs
  text/x-yaml                                     yml yaml
```

Comment: Is there also a solution for users that don't have root?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem anymore. The question is almost 5 (OMG!) years old. If it is: have you tried installing gmate? https://github.com/gmate/gmate. If you have the required dependencies intsalled you can install it on your user folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening up /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/ruby.lang again and addding this line at the top of the  section:

```
<property name="mimetypes=">application/x-ruby</property>
```

If that doesn't work, I'm stumped.

Comment: In my case, the above note helped me to find out, that Lua highlighting was attached to 'text/x-lua' mimetype; thanks.

Comment: also, I had to add some stuff to `~/.local/share/mime/packages/<SOMETHING>.xml`, see: http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mimetypes-database.html.en

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighting pulls its settings from XML lang files, although the Ruby lang file should automatically pick up on .rb files. To check, open the language file from /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/ruby.lang and see if *.rb is mentioned.

```
<property name="globs">*.rb</property>
```

Adding more Ruby extensions to the lang files:
http://blog.adsdevshop.com/2008/04/19/erb-syntax-highlighting-in-gedit/

Comment: Yeah, I've done that but it is not still not automatically working with Ruby files. I've noticed that the syntax highlighting is working automatically for other languages.